# Replacing substring with null for third occurrence

Tags: java, string, substring

How can I calculate the number of occurrences of a substring in a string and most importantly, if it occurs for the third time, the third substring will be replaced with (`""`)?

this is the sample input (the input format may be vary):
J9581 TAMAN MERLIMAU, JALAN MUAR, MERLIMAU, MELAKA,77300,MERLIMAU

expected output:
J9581 TAMAN MERLIMAU, JALAN MUAR, MERLIMAU, MELAKA,77300

Comment: Ok. Goahead and do it.

Comment: Can you share what you tried?

Comment: you can make use of [String#indexOf(String,int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String,%20int)). If you found a third occurence you could make use of [String#substring(int, int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) and [String#substring(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)). There are also other ways, like using `regex` and a [Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html).

Comment: `null` is not same as `""` (empty String)

Comment: Also, you should show us sample input and expected output

Comment: Have you read [the Java doc for String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)?  All the information you need is on that page.

Comment: @mimisya - Check Fido's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
String sentence = "J9581 TAMAN MERLIMAU, JALAN MUAR, MERLIMAU, MELAKA,77300,MERLIMAU";
String stringToReplace = "MERLIMAU";
int index = 0;
int occurrences = 0;
while ((index = sentence.indexOf(stringToReplace, index)) != -1) {
    ++occurrences;
    if (occurrences == 3) {
        sentence = sentence.substring(0, index) + sentence.substring(index + stringToReplace.length());
        break;
    }
    index += stringToReplace.length();
}

// Add this condition to remove the comma at the end if it exists:
if (",".equals(sentence.substring(sentence.length() - 1))) {
    sentence = sentence.substring(0, sentence.length() - 1);
}
```

Here is the result:

```
J9581 TAMAN MERLIMAU, JALAN MUAR, MERLIMAU, MELAKA,77300
```

Comment: simpler version. thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

**Step 1**: Get the indices of all occurrences of `word`:

```
String text = "abcHELLOdefHELLOghiHELLOjkl";
String word = "HELLO";
List<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = -1; (i = text.indexOf(word, i + 1)) != -1; ) {
    indices.add(i);
}
```

**Step 2**: Use the desired index as the start point for replacing the word

```
int desiredIndex = 3; //i.e. I want to remove the third occurrence of word
int index = indices.get(desiredIndex - 1); //Ideally should check if it found 3 occurrences
String newWord = text.substring(0,index) + text.substring(index + word.length());
System.out.println(newWord);
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: You need to check the size of that list before calling `indices.get()` - if there are less than 3 elements in it, you'll get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: @daiscog Agreed hence the comment. This example is just to show the principal of the method. OP can formalise as they see fit.

Comment: @Fido Fair enough.  (Incidentally, I also think using a list to store all the indices is a bit overkill when only the third index will ever be used.)

Comment: this will do. thanks everyone for quick reply! :)

Comment: @daiscog Once again, agreed. I just used the list to make the answer more readable. With simple questions like this I think it's best to leave optimizations up to the OP

Comment: @Fido I'm not convinced (given the apparent lack of effort shown in the question) that the OP has the experience to to make such optimisations.  I'm not trying to be critical, I just think it's worth noting these points for the OP (or anyone else who might read this) to consider.

Comment: @daiscog fyi, i have asked this question before with the coding and all but nobody answer. dont u think you being quite rude? still, thank you so much for your lovely comment :)

Comment: @mimisya He is not being rude at all. He is just trying to assure that the standards of stackoverflow remain high. His comments highlighted deficiencies in my code which yourself and other readers can improve upon. This common on stackoverflow :) . Every comment made by daiscog has added value to the answer.

Comment: @mimisya I meant no offence.  I meant that your question read as though you're an inexperienced programmer, and all of us have been inexperienced at one point.  My comments were intended to be helpful, not critical.